# KeyError while trying to create a bar graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, dataset

I am trying to plot a graph for the same 2 columns with this code:

```
plt.figure(figsize = (3,3)) 
df["gender", "heart_disease"].plot(kind = "bar")
plt.xlabel("heart_disease") plt.ylabel("gender")
```

this is the image after running the code from my previous question here This is Throwing an error, what is the right code for this?[this is the data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiztF.png)

and this is the error I am getting [this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Okdj1.png)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you didn't group by gender:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {
    'gender': ['Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female', 'Male'],
    'heart_disease': [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


plt.figure(figsize = (3,3)) 
df.groupby("gender")["heart_disease"].sum().plot(kind="bar")
plt.xlabel("heart_disease") 
plt.ylabel("gender")
plt.show()
```

[image: bar plot]

Answer (score 2):

## Using Pandas and Matplotlib

---

It looks like you configured the matplotlib graph size and x/y labels correctly, however the actual arguments for the bar graph itself seem to be the issue with your code. Because your pandas DataFrame **only accounts for whether or not a specific gender has a disease**, the actual number of subjects, `Male` or `Female`, **is not captured**. 


Consider using the below method where you iterate over the df and tally the rows where the `Male` and `Female` subjects have or do not have `heart_disease`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "gender": [...],
    "heart_disease": [...]
})

x = ["Male", "Female"]
y = [0,0] # Where index 0 is Male and index 1 is Female
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row["gender"] == "Male" and row["heart_disease"] == 1:
        y[0] += 1
    if row["gender"] == "Female" and row["heart_disease"] == 1:
        y[1] += 1

plt.bar(x,y, color = "black", edgecolor = "red")
plt.xlabel("X-Axis")
plt.ylabel("Y-Axis")
plt.show()
```

The documentation for this method and the method described by *@Mark* can be found here:

> [Pandas Iterator Over Rows](https://sparkbyexamples.com/python/iterate-over-rows-in-pandas-dataframe/) # The Iterator
>
> [Pandas GroupBy](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pandas/pandas-groupby-explained-with-examples/) #*@Mark*'s reference